# To get year from DateTimePicker and also to compare this year with previous year in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#q_dr_from").datetimepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',minDate: "-1Y", maxDate: "0"});
);

function find(){
 var fromDate = $("#q_dr_from").val();
    alert("fromDate" + fromDate);
    var year = fromDate.getFullYear();
    alert("year" + year); 
}
```

i am unable to display year it fails at var year = fromDate.getFullYear();.
and one more requirement is i want to compare this date with date 1 year ago from current date.
Could someone please help.

Comment: It's because your `fromDate` is simple string and not Date Object! And what you mean compare with date before year? It will always be -1 year.

Comment: `fromDate` is a string, not a Date. You should use `$("#q_dr_from").datetimepicker('getDate')`

Comment: hey Barmar.. when i am trying to get month as below:var frmDt =      $("#q_dr_from").datetimepicker('getDate');
    var year = frmDt.getFullYear();
    var month = frmDt.getMonth();   the result for month is 6 where i am expecting as 7(july)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
var fromDate = $("#q_dr_from").datetimepicker('getDate');
```

to get the date that the user selected.

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate

Comment: hey Barmar.. when i am trying to get month as below:var frmDt = $("#q_dr_from").datetimepicker('getDate'); var year = frmDt.getFullYear(); var month = frmDt.getMonth(); the result for month is 6 where i am expecting as 7(july). can you help me with this as well?

Comment: Javascript counts months starting from 0.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find object of your select date:
    var currentDateObj = new Date(fromDate);
    var year = currentDateObj.getFullYear();
    var previousYear = currentDateObj.setFullYear(year - 1);

```
Now you can compare between them
```